# Only one CSS transition works in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I'm trying to make change image size onclick in PhoneGap. I have code like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="saber"><div id="handle"><img src="imgs/handle.png"></div>
<div id="blade" class="blade-opened"><img src="imgs/blade-blue.png"></div></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $("#saber").bind( "click",
  function () 
   {
      if ($("#blade").height() > 0)
       {
      $("#blade").addClass("blade-closed"); 
     }
      else
       {
        $("#blade").removeClass("blade-closed");         
       }    
   }
   );
```

**CSS**

```
#blade
 {
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
 } 

.blade-opened
 {
  bottom: 5%;
  height: 81.25%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
 }

.blade-closed
 {
  bottom: 29%;
  height: 0;
 }  

#blade img
 {
  height: 100%;
 }
```

But when I open this on my phone, the image scales down with transition, but when I click once again, it just instantly appears after 1s.
Can anyone help me please?

Thank you very much.

**Edit**
I dont know what happened, but it is working now. I haven't change a thing. Strange... 
But now when I click something it gets highlited blue, which isn't very nice on images. Can someone help me?

Comment: I updated the answer, did that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kuxa,

change:

```
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
```

**to:**

```
    -webkit-transition: height 1s;
```

FWIW: this will work too:

```
    transition: height 1s;
```

You also need to set `position`, like this:

```
    position:relative;
```

I have not been able to find good documentation to explain this.

**UPDATE** I should have added, when using *position* any value can be used, except the "initial" state - [which is <s>`static`</s>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Summary)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to check height to add or remove class. Simply toggle class

```
$("#saber").bind( "click", function () {
    $("#blade").toggleClass("blade-closed"); 
 });
```

You need add class opened to increase height.

```
$("#saber").bind( "click",
  function () 
  {
  if ($("#blade").height() > 0)
   {
  $("#blade").removeClass("blade-opened");
  $("#blade").addClass("blade-closed"); 
 }
  else
   {
    $("#blade").removeClass("blade-closed");
    $("#blade").addClass("blade-opened");        
   }    
 });
```

Comment: Correct but won't fix op issue regarding animtion AFAIK

Comment: Thanx for a quick answer! Unfortunately, none of your suggestions fixes my problem. It disappears smoothly, but still appears instantly.